# Position Fixed with Position Relative

Tags: css, position, positioning, css-position

I have the following code:

```
<div class="main">
   <!-- CONTENT --> 
 <div class="tabs">
   <!-- CONTENT --> 
 </div>  <!-- Closing div for .tabs -->
 </div>  <!-- Closing div for .main -->

.tabs{
  position: fixed;
  top:110px;
  left:0px;
  width:40px;
  z-index:999
}
.main{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  position:relative;
}
```

From my understanding `position:fixed` is always relative to the browser window not the containing element. However I would prefer the `.tabs` div to be fixed but relative to the containing div. Is there anyway to have position fixed *and* have it relative to the containing element?

Comment: Use position: absolute.

Comment: @reinder - I could but I want the div to stay fixed on the page and not scroll off.

Comment: In that case you will need some javascript to calculate the position of the containing div. Fixed is always relative to the browser window (viewport) no matter what.

Comment: @reinder - Feel free to write that into an answer. JS is not always my strong suit =>

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/css-fixed-position-but-relative-to-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out this is a duplicate. The question referred to however assumes that the width of the containing element is known. If that's not the case you will need some javascript.
I made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6TyL4/

Please note that since fixed basically takes the element out of the container, the container element will not adjust in height width etc. and therefore doesn't actually "contain" the element.

```
$(function(){
    var t = $('.main').position().top;
    var l = $('.main').position().left;
    $('.tabs').css('top', t + 100).css('left', l + 100);
});
```

This will offset the .tabs 100px from the top and from the left relative to '.main'.