# position:fixed and width:inherit with percentage parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to give a *fixed* element a `width` of a percentage parent (here `#container`). When I use pixel instead of the percentage then it works. How can I do it? Is this possible with **CSS**?

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="fixed">
        Sitename
    </div>               
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{
  width:300px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;   
}

#container {
  width: 90%; /*When I use e.g 250 px it works. But I need it in percentage*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfA2Z/4/)

**Add:**

I need `position:fixed`. Because I want to place it at the bottom of the page like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfA2Z/8/)

Solution with `position:relativ` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why not use [javascript to set the width](http://jsfiddle.net/NfA2Z/7/)?

Comment: @Vucko: I thought I can do it without JavaScript. But maybe not?! Why it works with pixel and not with percentage value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed Position but Relative to Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Answer (score 6):

It seems as though the static value (250px) can be propagated through normal inheritance. Whereas when the relative value (90%) is being used, the fixed div has already been taken out-of-flow, and now inheritance-wise, its parent is the viewport. It seems to me that you're going to have to use good old js.

But, this question is months old now, so it probably doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Old questions always matter on StackOverflow- this is now one of the top search results for "position fixed width inherit."

Comment: No, there's nothing special in the way how position:fixed elements are treated when inheriting properties. The problem is both deeper and easier.

Answer (score 6):

There's a belief that inherited values are 'translated' from relative ones (such as percentages) into absolute ones. Guess what? It's wrong. Here's what MDN says about it:

> The `inherit` CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to
>   take the **computed value** of the property from its parent element.
>
> [...]
>
> The computation needed to reach the computed value for the property
>   typically involves converting *relative values* (such as those in `em units` or `percentages`) to *absolute values*. For example, if an element has specified values `font-size: 16px` and `padding-top: 2em`, then the computed value of padding-top is `32px` (double the font size).
>
> **However, for some properties (those where percentages are relative to
>   something that may require layout to determine, such as `width`,
>   `margin-right`, `text-indent`, and `top`), percentage specified values turn
>   into percentage computed values.** [...] These relative values that remain in the computed value become absolute when the *used value* is determined.

---

Now an example. Let's say we have the following structure:

```
<div id="alpha">
  <div id="bravo">
    <div id="charlie"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... and the following CSS:

```
#alpha { outline: 1px solid red; width: 420px; height: 100px; }
#bravo { outline: 1px solid green; width: 50%; height: inherit; margin: 0 auto; }
#charlie { outline: 1px solid navy; width: inherit; height: inherit; margin: 0 auto; }
```

... you'll see this picture:

[image: Width Inheritance Illustration]

... meaning that while `#charlie` element has the same height as its `#bravo` parent, its width is 50% of its parent. Inherited was a computed value: `100px` for height, `50%` for width.

---

While this feature might be good or bad, depending on situation, for non-fixed elements, it seems to be definitely hurting the fixed ones. As `50%` value for `width` property is inherited as is, the `used value` for that dimension will be based off the viewport. It's the same with `percentage-using` values, such as `calc(50%)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have #outer as width:300px, #container as 90% means 270px, now you have given width:inherit and position:fixed that is ambiguous to browser, so use position:fixed with width:x% for #fixed

Comment: I need the position:fixed because I want to place it fixed at the bottom of the page. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NfA2Z/8/ How I can get the 270px? Use JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

set the width of "fixed" to 100%, and give it (let's say) a position: relative instead of fixed.
http://jsfiddle.net/J7yE4/

```
#fixed {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in my case. I need position fixed, because it should be at the bottom of the page. Please  take a look http://jsfiddle.net/NfA2Z/8/

Comment: well. when you set width inherit - it does just that. your element inherits width of parent. in this case - it inherits 90%! (when you set parent to 250px - it inherits 250px)
the problem comes with position fixed. because the width is now calculated based on width of window.

Comment: Ok I see. I thought the width comes from the 300px from the #outer. So the solution in my case is to use JavaScript to get the width of #container?

Comment: well i think that will be the easiest solution here. ^^ (if not even the only one)
(in normal case - the width does come from parent, but not with position: fixed! =) it fixes it to window. )