# Inheriting width from Bootstrap container when child is position fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am trying to have a header div inherit its width from its parent. The header div is `position: fixed`. The parent is contained inside a bootstrap container.

However, as you can see in the code I've created, it is not correctly inheriting the width of its parent - it is adding some extra width from somewhere.

This is all very annoying! Any idea how to fix this?

```css
.category-body {
  margin-left: 17% !important;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}
.category-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="category-body">We are in the category-body
    <div class="category-header">We are in the category-header</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yVk15RqDqAac4H2eDJQe

Comment: Will the parent element always have a width of `67%`?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but your concept of inheritance is a bit off the mark. When you apply `position: fixed` to an element you remove it from the document flow. The element then has no parent, so there's nothing to inherit. More details [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)

Comment: @Michael_B That's not entirely true. Even though the element is removed from the document flow, it still does inherit a width of `67%`. It just doesn't work because the percentage is relative to the viewport and not the same container as the parent. The width *is* inherited. For instance, if the parent's width was `300px`, it [would work as expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/PD7jKEGgaba06NIorJHZ?p=preview). It just won't always work with percentage-based widths.

Comment: @Josh Corzier not nescessarily - only for min-width: 1200px. For smaller screen sizes it has margin-left/right: 100px (min-width: 992) or an empty .category-body{} below that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from using a percentage value on the parent `width`. Browsers seem to have a problem with this. (Tested on Chrome, FF & IE11.)

If you use pixel values the problem goes away.

[**Revise PLUNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vgAPfQ141PGBaAUghb9i?p=preview)

*From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21669505/3597276):*

> It seems as though the static value (250px) can be propagated through
>   normal inheritance. Whereas when the relative value (90%) is being
>   used, the fixed div has already been taken out-of-flow, and now
>   inheritance-wise, it's parent is the viewport.

Learn more here:

- [position:fixed and width:inherit with percentage parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17011195/3597276)
- [How can I make a fixed positioned div inherit width of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27982966/3597276)
- [Set a Fixed div to 100% width of the parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17806852/3597276)
- [Set width of a "Position: fixed" div relative to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5873565/3597276)
- [Set width of fixed positioned div relative to his parent having max-width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25999846/3597276)
- [Fluid width fixed position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12253803/3597276)

Comment: So by the looks of it, the only non-pixel way to do this is using javascript?