# Bootstrap 4 - Couldn't maintain the same width when affix the sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I'm working bootstrap 4. here i tried to add affix to the sidebar. I have added three columns for sidebar & made them fixed when meets the certain condition. But the problem is width is changing when the sidebar affix. So i want the sidebar with same width when it is normal & affixed. Please help me. Thanks in advance. **Note:** Please see the fiddle in desktop view.

```js
var toggleAffix = function(affixElement, scrollElement, wrapper) {

  var height = affixElement.outerHeight(),
    top = wrapper.offset().top - 58;

  if (scrollElement.scrollTop() >= top) {
    wrapper.height(height);
    affixElement.addClass("affix");
  } else {
    affixElement.removeClass("affix");
    wrapper.height('auto');
  }

};


$('#top-affix').each(function() {
  var ele = $(this),
    wrapper = $('<div></div>');

  ele.before(wrapper);
  $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    toggleAffix(ele, $(this), wrapper);
  });

  // init
  toggleAffix(ele, $(window), wrapper);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 3.625rem;
}

.container-fluid {
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.projects-wrp .title {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, from(#0a0b0c), color-stop(#121315), color-stop(#17191b), color-stop(#1d1f22), to(#222529));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #0a0b0c, #121315, #17191b, #1d1f22, #222529);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}

.projects-wrp .title h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.projects-wrp .affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3.625rem;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.projects-wrp .sidebar-lft h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="projects-wrp" style="height: 1500px;">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <h2 class="mb-0"> Avacadu.com[Onpage Seo Only]</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" id="top-affix">
          <aside class="sidebar-lft affix-container" style="background: #ccc;">
            <h4><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Categories</h4>
            <p class="mb-0">
              <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                            Link with href
                          </a>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <div class="card card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
            <p>sdfghjkliutrsdfgh</p>
          </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 dropped affix plugin [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components)

Comment: Yes i know that but i have written custom code for that.

Comment: Did u try sticky-top class from bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really an easy way for the sidebar to maintain relative (%) width once it's taken out of the flow of the DOM with `position:fixed`. Once it's "affixed" it becomes relative to the entire viewport, but not other elements on the page. This issue has been addressed in [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161665/inheriting-width-from-bootstrap-container-when-child-is-position-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Instead, you must use a **defined width** for the affix element:

```
#top-affix {
  max-width:300px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/rKPCFO7zF4

If you want to keep the sidebar a relative percentage based width, `position:sticky` may be a better option than `position:fixed`.

---

Related:
[Inheriting width from Bootstrap container when child is position fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161665/)
[How to create a sticky left sidebar menu using bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681895)
[Set width of a "Position: fixed" div relative to parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873565)