# Fixed position ignoring parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm alternating a div between `position: absolute` and `position:fixed` on scroll, you can see my broken code here (JSfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/g9NVj/2/

The areas in question are the pink and blue boxes that change colour when you scroll. The correct width and position (and the result I want) is the pink coloured box, the blue is broken. The blue box (`.fix`) changes to `position:fixed` and seems to hug the very left of the window and gets a different width (behind menu sidebar) and instead of using its parent.

I've tried adding position:relative to the parent but it doesn't fix the issue.

Here's a snippet of the key area of the fiddle but check JSFiddle for full code:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD5D5;
}

.c-2 {
    width: 50%;
    min-height:1px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: relative;  TRIED THIS BUT DOESN"T WORK */
}

.c-2.last {
    padding: 80px;
}

.sticky {
    z-index: -1;
    background: #e4f;
}

.fix {
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #34e;
}

.abs {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    left:0;
    background: #e4f;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed Position but Relative to Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Answer (score 0):

That is because `position:fixed` is relative to the browser window, so adding `position:relative` to the parent `div` doesn't help you. 
If you want the `.fix` `div` relative to the parent `div`, you should give it a `position:absolute` and the parent `div` a `position:relative`.

Comment: But this doesn't keep my div fixed in place though...?