# How to make an element fixed with respect to the parent?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a container div who's content is quite large.
The container is set to position: relative.
The content has another div which I would like for it to be fixed with respect to the container horizontally--it should still scroll vertically.

When I set the div in question to:

```
position: absolute;
left: mypreferredleftpx;
```

I got weird results.

---

### http://jsfiddle.net/Ey7vU/3/:

`PRETTY PICTURE` should scroll vertically, but not horizontally. It should remain fixed horiztontally with respect to the container.

Comment: share relevant html,css code

Comment: better fiddle it Ramin

Comment: Maybe your question is similar like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
position:relative
```

from `.container`

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey7vU/5/)

Comment: To explain, you're seeing `content` move, not `.pretty_picture`, when `.container` has relative positioning.

Comment: Hiral, I need the scroll to move pretty picture vertically, just not horizontally.

Comment: @Hiral, the horizontal scroll should keep the "PRETTY PICTURE" at the same place.