# Bootstrap: Fixed div flows outside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position, fixed

I'm having a problem where inside my header I have a div that I want to be fixed at the top as the user scrolls. However when I set position:fixed to the element it escapes the parent .container on the right side yet retains the padding on the left side.I am completely lost on this... Any advice would be greatly appreciated thanks!

HTML

```
<header class='banner'>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='site-header'>
          <div class='fixed-head'>
            <div class='site-nav col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-12'>
              <div class='row'>
                <div class='logo col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-9'>
                  <h1>Lend Lease <span>Love it!</span></h1>
                </div>
                <ul class='region-select col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-3'>
                  <li>
                      NSW <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='row'>
                <ul class='regions'>
                  <li>
                    QLD
                  </li><li>
                    SA
                  </li><li>
                    WA
                  </li><li>
                    VIC
                  </li><li>
                    ACT
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='register col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 pull-right'>
              <a href="#">Register for Updates <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/pencil.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
   .site-header {
      background: url(http://placehold.it/1140x500&text=Header+Image);
      background-position: center;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;


      .fixed-head {
         position: fixed;
         width: 100%;
         z-index: 99999;
      }

      .site-nav {
         background: @blue;

         h1 {
            margin: 0;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 18pt;
            padding: 15px 0px;
         }

         span {
            font-size: 14pt;
         }

         ul.region-select {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 0;
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
            li {
               display: inline-block;
               color: #fff;
               padding: 15px 30px;
               line-height: 2em;
               background: @orange;
               margin: 0;
               font-size: 12pt;

               span {
                  font-size: 10pt;
               }
            }

            .navicon {
               text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
               padding: 15px 10px;
            }
         }

         ul.regions {
            display: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            li {
               display: inline-block;
               background: #fff;
               width: 20%;
               text-align: center;
               padding: 15px;
               border-right: 1px solid @tan;

               &:last-child {
                  border: none;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      .register {
         background: @blue;
         padding: 15px 0px;
         font-size: 12pt;
         text-align: center;

         a {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12pt;
            line-height: 2em;
         }

         img {
            padding: 0 10px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg9mlzz4f7aelo9/Screenshot%202014-01-03%2015.47.16.png

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle if possible or provide a link for testing

Comment: `FIXED` element can't be re-positioned relative to its parent.

Comment: Check this 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position fixed elements does not care about parent positioning and box models. Hence given `width 100%;` to fixed element and not having `left/right` declared is causing the issue.

You also can not put fixed (hard code) value for left/right in this case. You have to take your containers left offset position and right offset position, then apply accordingly.

JS needed.

```
var leftPos = $(".site-header").offset().left  + "px";
$(".fixed-head").css({left: leftPos, right: leftPos});
```

Here leftPos value can be shared for both left/right of the fixed element. Because the container or your `.site-header` is always gonna be in center, means left space and right spaces would be equal.

*Now you can get rid of `width:100%` from `.fixed-head`.*