# Make column fixed position in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap, I have a grid column class="col-lg-3" that I want to place it in position:fixed while the other .col-lg-9 is normal position (scroll-able through the page).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Fixed content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>

</div>
```

Just the same way like the left column in [LifeHacker.com](http://lifehacker.com)
You will see that the left part is fixed however I scroll though the page.

I use bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: @Lowkase I attached the code per request.

Comment: Waiting for topic to be taken off "on hold".  In the meantime you can see my answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/dRbe4/.  I can explain it better once the question is reopened.

Comment: If anybody needs the right column to be fixed, combining `fixed-top` and `position-sticky` is [what worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75578716/5802289).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following the solution here http://jsfiddle.net/dRbe4/,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 fixed">
        Fixed content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 scrollit">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>

 </div>
```

I modified some css to work just perfect:

```
.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        width: 25%;
}
.scrollit {
        float: left;
        width: 71%
}
```

Thanks @Lowkase for sharing the solution.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same result without specify width attribute?

Comment: I realize this should be painfully obvious, but I can't get it to work...I want the scrollable column on the left and the fixed column on the right. My fixed column only has a label in it, but for some reason when I set these classes, the label "sticks" to the upper-left corner instead of being in the column. I've tried all different combinations of style attributes to no avail. Would appreciate a pointer :)

Comment: @ReidBelton share Jsfiddle so I can help you with the code.

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Thanks very much for the offer! Not necessary however as I've since shelved this project.

Comment: i did the same but when I'm adding the fixed class it's get disappeared. Please help.

Comment: Why not use bs grid classes for width?

Comment: Just remembering that with bootstrap 4 there is `.sticky-top`

Answer (score 100):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="affix">
           fixed position 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
       Normal data enter code here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely the preferred solution now!

Comment: This doesn't work properly on smaller screens, the right div will lay over the left col containing the `fixed` div

Comment: bootstrap 4?? any ideas

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, change 'affix' to 'sticky-top'

Comment: For info: Bootstrap dropped the support for affix with Bootstrap 4.0. Use 'position: sticky' now as suggested here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#components

Comment: Also using bootstrap 3. Is there a way to have it behave like position:sticky (where it scrolls until you reach the point)? I have a page layout with an element over the entire width of the top of the screen that scrolls out of view. If I use affix for my panel, it leaves an ugly gap where that element used to be on screen.

Answer (score 55):

iterating over Ihab's answer, just using `position:fixed` and bootstraps `col-offset` you don't need to be specific on the width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="position:fixed">
        Fixed content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work if you change the position of the columns

Comment: This is a better solution! work perfect and no CSS is needed.  @didando8a If you change the columns position just change the col-lg-offset to a new offset.

Comment: If someone need also Scrolling Ability to the fixed column, just add height and overflow. e.g. `style="position:fixed;height:100%;overflow-y:auto;"`.

Comment: @Roy "No CSS is needed" - yeah it is, its just in the style tag ;)

Comment: This is what I needed! Note the offset classes are different in Bootstrap 4, e.g. `offset-lg-3`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: instead of `position:fixed` style tag, you just add the `affix` class in BS3 and then the offset in the other column.

Comment: For bootstrap 4.x, add "position-fixed" to the classes of the col-lg-3 element, and then "offset-lg-3" to the other element.

Comment: This works for bootstrap 3.3!

Answer (score 29):

in Bootstrap 3 `class="affix"` works, but in Bootstrap 4 it does not.
I solved this problem in Bootstrap 4 with `class="sticky-top"`
(using `position: fixed` in CSS has its own problems)

code will be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="sticky-top">
            Fixed content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. `position-fixed` also worked for making the column stick to the top, however the contents of the column overflowed. `sticky-top` fixed that.

Answer (score 21):

**Updated for Bootstrap 4**

Bootstrap 4 now includes a `position-fixed` class for this purpose so there is no need for additional CSS...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="position-fixed">
                Fixed content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            Normal scrollable content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/yOF9csaptw

Comment: If I do as in your example, the content of the "col-lg-3" column goes out of its parent. Quite strange! (Try to put more text in this). It must be a bug...

Comment: It's not strange as [fixed position elements are removed from the normal DOM flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container). This is outside the scope of the original question, but would have to set specific size on the fixed element.

Comment: this causes the columns to overlap each other though

Comment: In my case this was preferred, as defining the position: fixed styling to the col-lg-3 div caused the cursors of the inner children elements to be shown as default (instead of fx. pointer).

Answer (score 6):

**Bootstrap 5**

The solution is [very similar to v4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182617/1453425), but you can use responsive variations with `.sticky-*-top` classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="sticky-md-top">
            Fixed content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>
</div>
```

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#responsive-sticky-top

Answer (score 4):

Use this, works for me and solve problems with small screen.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- (fixed content) JUST VISIBLE IN LG SCREEN -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 device-lg visible-lg">
       <div class="affix">
           fixed position 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    <!-- (fixed content) JUST VISIBLE IN NO LG SCREEN -->
    <div class="device-sm visible-sm device-xs visible-xs device-md visible-md ">
       <div>
           NO fixed position
        </div>
    </div>
       Normal data enter code here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap 4 just use [col-auto](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#margin-utilities)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto">
            Fixed content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            Normal scrollable content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work for me. both columns scroll as expected.

Comment: @star_trac try to add some css, should help: `.container-fluid {
flex: 1; }`

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do it that way, you can't do it in "col- *", because it's going to overlap each other, you should do it in the parent class "row", but depending on what you're doing, you might have a problem with the browser scroll that will be "cut" from the screen, however, is simple to solve, just control the column width and everything will be fine.

```
<div class="row fixed-top h-100">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Fixed content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 overflow-auto h-100">
        Normal scrollable content
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use .col instead of col-lg-3 :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      Fixed content
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-9">
      Normal scrollable content
   </div>
</div>
```