# Fixing position of one column with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

The page I am designing has a fixed header and in the row below it is has two Bootstrap columns, `.col-md-2` and `.col-md-10`.

I am trying to fix the header to the top of the page and the left column (`.col-md-2`) in the row below it to its position, however when I try to set `position: fixed;` in the CSS for the header and left column, the entire positioning of my page gets messed up.

Is there any way to safely lock in the position of a column in Bootstrap without throwing off the entire page *and* maintaining Bootstrap's classic responsiveness?

EDIT: Here is a [really, really bad demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oj1x34t4/) but it may give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. Here is a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6EhN.png)

The section with `HEADER` I want to be fixed to the top, the section with `ABOUT ME` I want to be in a responsive column fixed to the left, and the section with `POST` I want to be in a responsive, not fixed column to the right that allows for scrolling.

One of the problems with the solution I have now is when I try to decrease the browser-width all of the text in the column to the right gets smushed down and doesn't act like a Boostrapped column would at all.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your code?

Comment: @cchapman900 I just added a demo that may help give more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is a mix of 2 demos :

1st the top navbar (will be the header in your case) fixed by [bootstrap here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)...

2nd [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070691/1720332) for the left col fixed positioning...

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much! Those are both exactly what I was looking for. I'll just need to pad the nav bar down a bit but everything is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Add .hidden-xs to your .col-md-4 and add .col-xs-12 to your .col-md-8

Once on smaller devices this will hide the left col-4 and let your col-8 keep its place below the header... Hoping that you do not need to keep the col-4 (?)

Edit : I assumed you mistyped, col-8 beeing the right col and not the left one...

Comment: I added a demo and more context to my original question that may help you see what I want to accomplish.