# make a column on bootstrap fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap and I want to make a div fixed and scroll only content, like how Facebook uses the right sidebar fixed and the timeline scrolled.

**I WANT THE SAME AS FACEBOOK** NOT LIKE THE OTHER PROPOSITION ON STACKOVERFLOW

my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 layout-content-container">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 layout-content-container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to make the col-md-8 scrolled and the col-md-4 fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make column fixed position in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868610/make-column-fixed-position-in-bootstrap)

Comment: no it doesnt work for me i want the same as facebook not like this maybe with a javascript code or something but i want the same as facebook

Comment: You aren't showing us any css. Could you post your CSS as well? At this point, you literally only have boilerplate HTML...

Comment: How is the duplicate different from what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, it may be a *possible* duplicate, but it wasn't. I retract my close vote, I apologize I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `position:fixed` to attach the sidebar...

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/oThW0CigtE