# Two Bootstrap columns when left is fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a two column layout where left column has a fixed position. My problem is that the right column's content goes underneath the fixed one. Here is a basic structure:

```
<body style="overflow:auto">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 left">
      1234
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div>
          Content
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mjpcgt4/2/)

Comment: possible duplicate [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868610/make-column-fixed-position-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add margin-left:100px(width of the left div) to the second div.it should fix your problem

check this snippet

```css
.left {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body style="overflow:auto">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 left">
        1234
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumAt vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos
          ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
          Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus
          autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur
          aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
          ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
          laborumAt vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
          deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
          omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a
          sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, that works. It also works with my overall scrolling solution. Thanks!