# How to make fixed position row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I have a table-like structure, where the first `<div class="row">...` behave as the header for the table.
I am trying to make it fixed, so when I scroll down the page, users can still see the columns headings.
I gave it position:fixed, which achieves that, but now, the width of the columns is trashed.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="position:fixed;">
                <div class="col-md-1">id</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">L Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">M</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">F Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">Username</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">Phone</div>
            </div><!-- row -->
<!-- some data -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">id</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">L Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">M</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">F Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">Username</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">Phone</div>
            </div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

I really needs this to work on Chrome/FF/Safary. IE is not a concerns

Comment: See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it 
`<div class="container" style="position: fixed">`
EDIT: I create simple example at http://jsfiddle.net/ytJV7/2/

Comment: Or positioning header to 'absolute'

Comment: I need the top of the grid to stay at the same place when I scroll down. Not the entire container to stay, as I am scrolling that container

Answer (score 1):

There is also [sticky-top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#sticky-top) class in bootstrap CSS

[Fiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/1ue72ap9/)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row sticky-top bg-white">...
```

Comment: My preferred solution, for BS4 (at least) as it uses their built in classes