# Centralize div with display inline-block and position relative

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to centralize in the vertically and horizontally, but without success:

https://jsfiddle.net/szg7hhph/1/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div id="new__event">
  <div class="target">
    <h2>Free Pass</h2>
  </div>
</div>


body {
  margin: 0;
}

#new__event {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
#new__event {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
#new__event .target {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 48px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: white;
  color: #f98835;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
```

I already try margin 0 auto, text-align, vertical-align, but the box persist in the corner..

Comment: Is it possible to set a fixed height for the box?

Comment: Then, unfortunately, you can't really center it unless you first find out what hight it ends up being using javascript.  Maybe you could instead have your dialogue be 20 or 30 pixels offset from the top rather than truly centered?

Comment: @JosephMarikle It’s possible using `transform`. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the `position` of `#new_event .target` to `absolute`, remove the `margin-top` property and add the following new properties:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
left: 25%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

This should work starting from IE 9.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution!  I'll have to use that myself.  It's slightly off because of a top margin, but it seems to work perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/kya72gdd/  I was wrong in assuming it couldn't be done without a fixed height.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks :-) You’re right, it’s slightly off due to the `margin-top` property. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: but what if i want put one more target? they last will be upon the first

Comment: @DRX In this case, you might want to add a wrapper div (which gets the `transform` property and the related stuff).