# CSS/SASS method for fixing div

Tags: html, css, typescript, sass

I hope you'll have an answer for me.
In CSS there's the property background-attachment: fixed; which looks really fancy, so my question is there any property which I can use to "fix" some divs with text's etc. in the document?
If not, how to solve it in Typescript?
I hope you know what I mean

//edit:
Okay, i will try to describe it: with the property background-attachment: fixed; the background of a div is fixed but not it's content, so a parallax effect appears, like this: w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm And know I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same with the content like texts etc.

Comment: Please don't down vote this question like this. It's actually a good question in terms of design. See my answer as below.

Comment: Can you share some relevant code snippets to increase the clarity of the question.

Comment: I think, your question is answered below. Please let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it like this ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixedContainer">
    This is experimental
</div>
<div class="otherContainer"> </div>
```

And here goes your style

**CSS**

```
<style>
.fixedContainer {
    background-color:#ddd;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.otherContainer {
    height:1000px;
    background-color:#bbb;
}

</style>
```

**Credit originally goes to** : this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jz1yvr/) and stackoverflow user [aaronk6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387396/aaronk6) and [Joseph Marikle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph-marikle) at their posts :

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container) and at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773701/centralize-div-with-display-inline-block-and-position-relative/28773941#28773941) respectively.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, the fixedContainer is fixed but not that fixed i want, maybe when I say the word "parallax fixed"? you know what i mean?

Comment: Nope, I didn't .What is "parallax fixed" ?

Comment: Okay, i will try to describe it: with the property background-attachment: fixed; the background of a div is fixed but not it's content, so a parallax effect appears, like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm      And know I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same with the content like texts etc.

Comment: Here an attachment (as background) is fixed. It's an image. But you want it to be a div (with some text content) fixed here right ?

Comment: yes right. The background in my div is already fixed  (and looks nice btw), but i also want the content to be fixed like the background.

Comment: Can you check out this one : https://davidwalsh.name/demo/parallax.php ,
If it helps you !

Comment: Also you may check this like : http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/practical-css-parallax/feature-detection/

Comment: I think i will look at transform translate and i hope i will get it. thanks