# How to center a fixed element both vertical and horizontal without fixed 'width' & 'height'?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed element without width and height,just contain some flexible text. When I want to center there text vertically and horizontally, I failed. How to achieve? Thanks :)

[There is a link be used to reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container/6794097#6794097)

```
body{
  background: #f63;
}
div{
  background: #069;
  color:#fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;

}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
div {
  background: #069;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily achieve by css3 transform properties

```
**vertically Middle**

div{
  background: #069;
  color:#fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

For **Horizontal** you need width or else

```
div{
      background: #069;
      color:#fff;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
      transform:translateX(-50%);
     //comes horizontally center as per elements width
      left:50%;
      right:0;
    }
```