# Elements don't float inside a fixed div?

Tags: html, css

So, I tried to create 2 floating divs inside a parent div whose `position` is set to `fixed` and the 2 children floats to `left` and `right`. But for some reson the code is not working as expected. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/cqn73m0p/
What I tried to achieve is make these 2 children divs float according to their CSS property i.e. to the left and right. I don't like to assign width to each child elements as it will make the code non-responsive.
Here is what I tried
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="top-nav">
        <section>
            <div class="left">left</div>
            <div class="right">right</div>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav.top-nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}
.left{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.right{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.topnav` does not have width.  In regards to the fixed nav not confining itself to the container, [Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container) will probably help you.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; //added so right is visible
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <section>
        <div class="left">left</div>
        <div class="right">right</div>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that!