# Align paragraph with two spans on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating an arcade game with JavaScript and jQuery. In this game, I need to align the level, score and high score in the same line.

My HTML structure looks like this

```
<div class="game-info">
  <p id="level">
    <span id="score"></span>
    <span id="high-score"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

For the CSS, I want to provide some breathing room, between the paragraph and the two spans. Span elements are by nature `inline` elements so they should be able to be on the same line.

```
#score, #high-score {
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code I have

```
$("#level").html("<strong>Level: </strong>" + level + 
"<span id='score'>Score: " + score + "</span><span id='high-score'> High Score: " + 
highScore() + "</span>");
```

As you can see, I have clearly wrapped everything in span elements.

I'd like it to look like this

```
Level: 1         Score: 4      High Score: 16
```

However, it has some crazy effects.

It will start out with the value for high score on it's own line. And after 5 or 6 correct answers in a row, it will line up on the correct line. Later, if you score more than 10, it will drop back to a new line.

Here's the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mypkktu7/1/

I do not understand this weird behavior.

Is there anything I can do to fix it? Something like using a `min-width` property?

Comment: Can't you simplify the demo down to a minimal representation of the problem? Not easy to inspect css while having to play a game that removes those elements

Comment: And we should have to stop to figure out how that works. No. An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is more appropriate and not unreasonable to ask for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `white-space: nowrap;`

to your paragraph tag css and you'll be good.

## Css

```
#level {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

white-space has a hyphen in between to break the words

Comment: `whitespace` doesn't work but `white-space` does. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.game-info {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

P.S. : It's a fun game :)

Comment: This is acceptable as well if you want the div to cover the full width

Comment: Interesting. I thought that `p` elements by default, as block level elements took up the entire width

Comment: The parent element has a fixed position. The problem with using "fixed" positioning is that it takes the element out of flow. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)