# Fixed div with 100% width in body-content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and am trying to fix a div to the top of the `body-container` div.
Using this css, I am able to accomplish fixing the div to the top of the container, but it spills outside the right of the `body-container` div:

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-bar .item-count h4{   
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the all my html/css: https://jsfiddle.net/rttvqa3k/

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? You want to position that top bar inside your `body-content` element? Because if that's the case you shouldn't be using `position: fixed` , the element will be positioned relative to the viewport not the parent element.

Comment: I am trying to get `top-bar` to be a sticky element at the top of `body-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this if its helpful.. :)

OLD:

```
<div class="top-bar panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 matter-count">
            <h4>### Items in Report</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NEW:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-top container" style="top:60px;">    
    <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-body row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 matter-count">
            <h4>### Items in Report</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks! I assume that the navbar-fixed-top uses bootstrap.js functionality?

Comment: Your Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794097/540756) explains the issue with `position: fixed` relative to a container. The answer does offer ways to accomplish this but it deals with known widths.

> The problem with using "fixed" positioning is that it takes the
>   element out of flow. thus it can't be re-positioned relative to its
>   parent because it's as if it didn't have one.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that answer, but I am not dealing with known widths. I was hoping to use just bootstrap/css, but if that's not possible I'll have to use some javascript.

Comment: Seems like pure CSS solution might be a little hacky. Have you looked into using [Bootstrap's affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that before, I'll check that out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width or the max-width (.top-bar width 750px) of the fixed element, but then you will have to deal with the media queries for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post this so that you get things clear since it would be too long for a comment in the answer marked as correct.

There are several values you can use in the CSS property `position`.

**Static**, which is the default, **relative**, **absolute** and **fixed**.

Read more about that **[here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)**.

---

If you use `position: fixed;` without defining `top` and `left` values, your element will default these values to where its parent element is rendered.

Here's an example for clarity:

If your body content has `padding-left: 15px;` your element with `position: fixed;` will have a default value of `left: 15px;`. The same goes for top, if your parent element is positioned (X)px top from the viewport, lets say X equals to 60 your `position: fixed;` element will default to `top: 60px;`

You can see this behavior here: *(Notice that I did not reference bootstrap.js so you can see it has nothing to do with your problem.)*

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1030;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 135px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1030;
  width: 100%;
}
.top-bar .matter-count h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container body-content">


    <div class="top-bar panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 matter-count">
          <h4>### Items in Report</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Some region
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        some content
        <br/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br/>some more content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br/>event more content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Some region
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        some content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />some more content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />event more content
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Some Application</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>
```

---

So the correct approach is to set this properties so they don't *default*.

This way:

```
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 135px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
}


.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-bar .matter-count h4{   
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
    
    
    <div class="top-bar panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 matter-count">
            <h4>### Items in Report</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Some region
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        some content
        <br/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br/>
        some more content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br/>
        event more content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Some region
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        some content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        some more content
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        event more content
    </div>
</div>
    
    <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Some Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add overflow-x to your class description. This will add a scroll bar when needed

```
    overflow-x:auto;
```

Comment: OP is not looking to add a scroll bar. This is a problem involving the correct positioning of elements.

Comment: @Ricardo Ruiz, OP stand for? I saw many users are using this word on stackoverflow. I'm new here.

Comment: @Claus It's a slang commonly used in boards/forums, short for Original Poster.

Comment: did not ask for definition of OP