# DIV bigger than parent with overflow:hidden; position: relative

Tags: css

How can I display a DIV which is bigger than its ancestor, when the ancestor DIV has style `overflow: hidden; position: relative;`?

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  __________________________SHOW_ME
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here is this example on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss9gf0fy/1/).

I tried styling the content DIV with various combinations of `position: absolute`, `overflow: visible`, `right: -100px`, but it didn't help.

How can I style the content div so that it is entirely visible?
I cannot modify the parent DIV with `container` class, only the content inside.

Comment: short version: you can't. long version: you can use position fixed, but then the content div will scroll with the screen

Comment: i think, that you have to somehow modify `.container` to `overflow:visible` or its width

Comment: @Pete thanks, position:fixed would work for me. Would you post that as Answer ?

Comment: Ah, give it to Erikzy - I don't think it's a good enough solution to warrant a full answer because of the scrolling defect - if I were to use js to fix that, instead, I would probably just wrap the container and move the content into the wrapper

Comment: Why do you need (or can't remove) `overflow: hidden` on the parent?

Comment: Check this answer in the dupe link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11833892/2827823

Answer (score 0):

if you want the content's position to be tied to the container, you basically can't unless you use javascript to update the position on scroll and set the position of the content to be fixed instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't show div inside element using `overflow:hidden`, But I have solution for you.
You can give your div with `overflow:auto`, so user can scroll x

[Here the example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss9gf0fy/2/)

Comment: thanks, but scroll looks ugly :-)

Comment: The best solution is change the `overflow:hidden;` in your `.container` why you don't do that?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
        __________________________SHOW_ME
  </div>
</div>
```