# Fixed navbar under cover image

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a little problem. I'm building my portfolio and make the cover image on the begining but under that image I want to dispaly the fixed-top navbar which will follow me on the entire page. So how can I hide it under the cover image ? I hope you understand my problem :slight_smile: Thanks in advance :slight_smile:

I did what i want with z-index property. I gave 1 to image cover and 0 to others elements. Do you think that is a good idea ?

Comment: You should add your code and what you already have done.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Dzonyy/pen/RoKmoe It's fast copy from my PC so I didn't add images :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions and I do not know yours. But be sure to set div containing your "nav-bar" to position: fixed;

[You will find some answers here, I hope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Comment: My navbar works properly but I want to hide it under cover image and display it under on other sections.