# Fixed side navigation in container

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

Im making a side navigation in container. I want to make that navigation with `fixed` position and 100% of side `div` width. I'm making site with Bootstrap, and I can't find solution for that. There in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/c8jL3zxd/) have a example of that.

There's CSS of menu

```
.menu{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: is it what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/9frn04aw/ ?

Comment: See this example since you use BS https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: @Banzay I want to make it Fixed in side div

Comment: @DincaAdrian do you seen my fiddle?

Comment: here is a solution using bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/t3kfp7bs/1/

Answer (score 0):

The main issue (or quality, it depends) with position fixed is that moves the element out of the structure. 
So you can't put it under a parent container (as you tried to do) because there is no parent container.

For more infos see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container) question where you can find some workarounds to solve your problem.