# How to I fix a 100vh div to the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix a google map within a div to screen. The map on the left side should be fixed while the content on the right sided should be scroll. Not sure how to achieve this as I am using `position:fixed` but it doesn't seem to do the trick See pictures.

Tried using the following but didn't work:

```
#map {
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}


<div class="mapViewTitle">
    <h3>Searching:</h3>
    <div class="typeMap">
        <p>Single Family Homes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="priceMap">
        <p>From $200,000 to $300,000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mapDetail">
        <p>3+ br</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mapDetail">
        <p>2+ bth</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="searchResultsMapRight">
    <div class="propertyOverview mapView">
        <img src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap1.png" alt=""
            class="propertyImage">
        <div class="quickDetails">
            <p>5689 Main Ave</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>
            <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quickFacts">
            <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>
            <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>
            <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>
            <div class="like mapViewDetail"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="propertyOverview mapView">
        <img src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap2.png" alt=""
            class="propertyImage">
        <div class="quickDetails">
            <p>5689 Main Ave</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>
            <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quickFacts">
            <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>
            <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>
            <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>
            <div class="like mapViewDetail"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="propertyOverview mapView">
        <img src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap3.png" alt=""
            class="propertyImage">
        <div class="quickDetails">
            <p>5689 Main Ave</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>
            <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quickFacts">
            <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>
            <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>
            <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>
            <div class="like mapViewDetail"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

[image]

[Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Comment: Give your complete code

Comment: just added the code

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have the screen divided into two parts one is fixed with the google map and another has the ability to scroll.

So you need to add

```
#map {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
}
```

This will cover the full half and Now you can adjust the position by changing the value of `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`.

If not you can see my work on google map here http://wherewheater.bitballoon.com/

Comment: @Insivika  use overflow-y: auto;

Comment: You will have to add all the stuff in right side div

Answer (score 0):

```js
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
```

```css
#map{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBlzZ0CNZ-rHjNp_CI5VFc9QvvitzrOVjk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: 100vh will not make the position fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try `#map { position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; }` `bottom: 0;` will be fill your div.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a lot of classes in your code. It may help to enclose them in div ids rather than sections ( I saw an end section tag but not a beginning?) 
In below snippet I have added 2 divs (with ids) separating the 2 code sections. I set the map at 90vh with a small margin - it's easier on the eye i find - but set to 100vh if you wish.

Hope this helps

```css
#map {
  margin: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#match {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"> <!---enclosed iframe of map in div id-->
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d26446.690472440776!2d-118.35891963889674!3d34.04806981747934!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x80c2b8f9683c5e93%3A0xeaed7d9ab5bc2296!2sLos+Angeles%2C+CA+90019%2C+USA!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1513898452752"
    width="100%" height="100%" ; frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>


<div id="match"> <!---inserted separate div id here--->
  <div class="mapViewTitle" data_liveedit_tagid="000000001A4CF100">
    <h3>Searching:</h3>

    <div class="typeMap">
      <p>Single Family Homes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="priceMap">
      <p>From $200,000 to $300,000</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mapDetail">
      <p>3+ br</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mapDetail">
      <p>2+ bth</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="searchResultsMapRight">
    <div class="propertyOverview mapView"><img alt="" class="propertyImage" src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap1.png">
      <div class="quickDetails">
        <p>5689 Main Ave</p>

        <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>

        <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
      </div>

      <div class="quickFacts">
        <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>

        <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>

        <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>

        <div class="like mapViewDetail">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="propertyOverview mapView"><img alt="" class="propertyImage" src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap2.png">
      <div class="quickDetails">
        <p>5689 Main Ave</p>

        <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>

        <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
      </div>

      <div class="quickFacts">
        <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>

        <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>

        <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>

        <div class="like mapViewDetail">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="propertyOverview mapView"><img alt="" class="propertyImage" src="resources/img/samplePropertyMap3.png">
      <div class="quickDetails">
        <p>5689 Main Ave</p>

        <p>Los Angeles, CA 90019</p>

        <p class="priceDetail">$556,000</p>
      </div>

      <div class="quickFacts">
        <div class="quickFact1">2 br</div>

        <div class="quickFact2">2 bth</div>

        <div class="quickFact3">4,000 SF</div>

        <div class="like mapViewDetail">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```