# Fixed position relative to parent not browser

Tags: html, css

I want right and left side divs to be fixed in position with class main-wrapper in line with blue color box...Right now its taking top position with the header.Want it to be floating fixed not absolute.it shoulds tick to the main-wrapper.position top:0 to main-wrapper.Tried almost everything not working.

below is the code:

```css
.header{
     width:500px;
     margin:0 auto;
     background:red;
     height:300px;
}
 .container{
     margin:20px auto;
     background:blue;
     height:1000px;
    width:500px;
}
 .header-wrapper,.main-wrapper{
     width:100%;
}
 .main-wrapper{
     position:relative;
}
 .left-ad,.right-ad{
     width:100px;
     height:250px;
     background:pink;
     position:fixed;
}
 .left-ad{
    left:0;
     top:0;
}
 .right-ad{
    right:0;
     top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="left-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="right-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container) FYI, typing “position fixed relative to parent” into Google would have easily gotten you there. Please make an actual effort.

Comment: Bbroe did that bt couldnt get

Comment: Then you should at least mention that upfront in your question, and describe what you have tried and with what results.

Comment: i dont need a suggesstion ..need a solution.....and i think no one mentions the story of how they tried...its only query to be mentioned.

Comment: Please go read [ask]! It very explicitly tells you that we expect you to show us what you tried. The purpose of this site is not to provide you with copy&paste-ready “solutions” all the time, without you making any reasonable effort in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied position:sticky property to make left and right div to be position fixed absolute.[Position Property](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="left-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="right-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>

`.header { 
      width:500px;
      margin:0 auto;
      background:red;
      height:500px;
 }
.container { 
     margin:20px auto;
     background:blue;
     height:1000px;
     width:500px;
}
.header-wrapper, .main-wrapper { 
    width:100%;
}
.main-wrapper { 
    position:relative;
}
.left-ad, .right-ad {     
     position: sticky; 
     width:100px;
     height:250px;
     background:pink;
 }
.left-ad {float:left; left:0; top:0; }
.right-ad {float:right; right:0; top:0; }`
```

Comment: oh it worked......thanks a lot.ill soon apply to the website n check....

Comment: it doesnt support ie 11.so we need a hack or put something manually?

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you want ??**

Add `top` value to the `.left-ad,.right-ad` selector.

```css
.header{
     width:500px;
     margin:0 auto;
     background:red;
     height:300px;
}
 .container{
     margin:20px auto;
     background:blue;
     height:1000px;
     width:500px;
}
 .header-wrapper,.main-wrapper{
     width:100%;
}
 .main-wrapper{
     position:relative;
}
 .left-ad,.right-ad{
     width:100px;
     height:250px;
     background:pink;
     position:fixed;
}
 .left-ad{
     left:0;
     top:328px;
}
 .right-ad{
     right:0;
     top:328px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="left-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="right-ad">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```