# How to fix top bar present in left side Grid using css without overlapping it to the next right side Grid element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui and react, I need to fix the top bar(not at the top of the page), which is a top bar for a Grid element(parent).

I tried to fix the topbar(child) with this: 

`navigation: {
    position: 'fixed',
    maxWidth: '47vw',
}`

And the Grid(parent) is: 

  `root: {
     maxWidth: '100vw',
  }`

**But if the width of the Grid(parent) changes, the topbar will overlap on the other Grid element which is there next to its parent.** How can we fix this overlapping? Or is there any solution with the css property flex which inherits the parent's properties?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue.  It is very hard trying to understand what your problem is with what you have provided

Comment: Also `position:fixed` doesn't *sound* like the way to go/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container : My question was this actually.

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI is using `display: flex` as default and in flex system for avoiding such things you have to use `flex-grow: 1`
for example, if you need that element to occupy some blocks you must use `flex-basis` and for growing with changing the resolution of the page for each element you must set the `flex-grow: 1` that means that specific item growing same as the others grow
for flex-basis read this:
[Flex-basis on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-basis)

and for flex-grow read this:
[Flex-grow on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-grow)