# How to float a button in a responsive way?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a webform and the user needs to click on 'save' often. So I'm trying to float the Save Button.

```css
#floatButton {
   position: fixed;
   top: 900px;
   right: 90px;   
   text-align: center;    
}
```

```
<div id="floatButton">
    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" 
    onclick="SaveButton_Click" Text="Save" / >
</div>
```

The button looks good and floats with my current display settings(standard resolution). But on different display settings the button goes out of the form either towards the right of the form or at the bottom. I tried setting the  position to 'relative' and 'absolute'. It didn't help. I would like to have the button within the form in all resolutions. How do I set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try position: relative; for parent div and position: absolute for .floatbutton and fix the top and left accordingly

Comment: so do i need to add two divs?

Comment: in your parent div that means the form div give position relative

Comment: can u add a jsfiddle or code pen of ur code so that i can help u

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container helped.Thanks!