# Fixed element inside mat-sidenav-content

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, fixed, mat-sidenav

I would like to have a fixed element inside of `mat-sidenav-content` while still allowing the user to scroll the content behind it when their mouse is over the fixed element.

Here is a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khterh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Notice that when your cursor is over the list of `div`s, they scroll as expected, but if your cursor goes over the fixed element you cannot scroll.

I would like to avoid simply adding `pointer-events: none` to the fixed element because there will be interactive functionality on it eventually. The left sidenav should stay where it is.

The solutions discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container) seem relevant but I have not been able to implement them successfully here.

Answer (score 0):

In the `template`, add `(wheel)` to your fixed element as follows.

```
<div class="inner-sidenav" (wheel)="onWheel($event)">...</div>
```

In the `component` class, add corresponding `onWheel` function.

```
onWheel(event: WheelEvent): void {
    (<Element>event.target).parentElement.scrollTop += event.deltaY;
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhatu9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please read the question more carefully: `I would like to avoid simply adding pointer-events: none to the fixed element because there will be interactive functionality on it eventually`

Comment: Sorry for not carefully reading your question. I edited my answer and provide a hopefully more accurate solution.