# How to fix div only inside my another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, vs-web-site-project

**Fix only with another div **

Here is the code that I used...
HTML code,

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="fix">
            Here fixed content
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS code,

```
.container{
    display:flexbox;
    height: 40em;
    background-color: black;
}
.fix{
    position: fixed;
    width: 25em;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make the element's parent container have position: relative**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guru 
**fixed** work globe on page.
If you want to work in "container" you should use **position:sticky** instead **fixed**