# element positioning fix in dynamic situation

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I am using Bootstrap and I want to have the **top-right side of the red background** always **sit** to the **top right corner of the blue section in the visible section regardless of how window resized as it is responsive**.

Red should be position fixed as it should not be moved by scrolling but always should sit on the right-top side of the visible blue background section.

as the picture it should be like this :
[image]
If I scroll ( I did it with windows paint now)

[image]

Please check the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bigmantana/kbpjd2xr/24/) or see the below codes :

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 18%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-11 left">left

    </div>
    <div class="col-1 right">right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Comment: No that is different. In my case the position that the red layer needs to be fixed is dynamic to the visible area. It is easy to have it always in the left side or on top but not in the right side. At least I still do not know how to do it

Comment: The reason you are getting answers that are not what you want is because it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. Your js fiddle looks like what you have described, but obviously it isn't so can you explain what it is doing that is wrong? Or if you had an example, it would be easier to understand if we could see what you mean.

Comment: Hi, you changed the my code and actually it was not what I wanted. In your revision the result was not what I wanted. When you scroll the page the red element disappear and I wanted to be fixed regardless of the window size and position in the top right side of the blue size ( which depends on the window size)

Comment: I didn't actually change your code, I just wrapped the code in snippet tags. Part of the reason you are having problems is because you are using columns in a layout that doesn't have columns - you are moving the last column out. Do you need the column layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the element at the top of the right, and it should be outside the another element without scrolling, you can use **position: absolute** property
Try this solution:

```
.right{
  background-color: red;
  width: '100%';
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no it does not work like that. It still could go of from the visible top right corner of the blue

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, please add **position: relative** for _.row_ class

Comment: This does not solve the problem. You can check it your self in the link that I provided

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `position: sticky` in this case. There's a few things you need to do to make this work:

1. Set the `position: relative` on the the element's parent (the `.row` in this case)
2. Set a `top` value on the sticky element. This is needed so when the element switches to sticky, it knows where to position it.
3. I added another class to the `.right` element, because Bootstrap's `col` classes were more specific. Adding class `.sticky` to that element, makes sure the position property is applied.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}


.left {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
}

.right.sticky {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  right: 18%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-11 left">left

    </div>
    <div class="col-1 right sticky">right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks disinfor, but still there is a problem. If I shrink the browser width the red will be disappeared ( I want to red part be visible not only when you scroll vertically but also when you shrink the browser width. Thanks

Comment: @Sami I don't see that happening. Run my snippet full screen and you can test it. Do you have other code on your site hiding the `.right` element?

Comment: @disninfor no basically I resize browser in here and I see when I shrink the browser the red could not be seen.

Comment: Yeah, because the red element is dropping below. Do you need columns? Why not start with the red element INSIDE of the blue column?