# How to make a fixed position div in center

Tags: css, css-position

I have two 50% width divs and want to make a div(which is inside one of them) to be position fixed and center.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/khamran1/pen/poEYmOg). Please have a look at it to get a better idea about the problem. Also I have embed my code here as well.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="floating"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}
p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.first {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
}
.second {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.floating {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
}
```

**PS** I know its possible with position sticky but I don't want to use it. You can add the below code in `.floating` class and it will be in center.

```css
    position: sticky;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6794000/2444959

Comment: If `.second` is also `fixed` you can position `.floating` relative to it. Will that work for you?

Comment: no `.second` is not fixed only the `.floating` inside it is `fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: translate(-50%)` with `left: 50%`:

```css
.centered {
  background: forestgreen;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centered"></div>
```

`

Comment: this will make the `.floating` div to be in the page center not in the center of `.second` div

Comment: I’m not sure that is possible. `fixed` positioning sits on top of the *viewport*, unless there is an ancestor with a `fixed` position. You might need to use javascript to figure out the position you want and set the `right` and `top` properties accordingly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#fixed_positioning

Answer (score 0):

Set the position relative to second element and than set the box in center with position absolute like this:

```
.second {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.floating {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Comment: this will make the `.floating` to have an absolute not **fixed**

Comment: It is fixed to the center related with parent

Comment: maybe my question didn't speak out like I want to. So basically I want the `.floating` div to be in the center of `.second` div with positon fixed

Comment: Position fixed with position element based on the body and not on the parent so the only way is to use position absolute since this element is inside .second element

Comment: yes you're right but I want to make the div that's inside to be position fixed. Using absolute will make its position static which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="first">
 </div>
 <div class="second">
 </div>
 <div class="floating"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

You can show full code in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiihd/su0Lhnjk/42/)

Comment: this is the page center. I want to make it center aligned to `.second` div with `position: fixed`

Comment: Just try-  left: 75%; and transform: translateX(-50%); for horizontal centre.  It will work surely.