# I am a beginner in html. I created a toggle using javascript. When I added a toggle the other content of the website is moving down . How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    [with toggle effect the carousal is also moving which I don't want][1]
    
    
    [without toggle the carousal is at right place ][2]
    
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84qYC.jpg
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJ8P.jpg
    
    
    Here is the code html code

  /*html code*?
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-row justify-content-between align-items">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="logo.png">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="nav-toggler">
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
        <div class="display-flex">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div id="news-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-grid-image">
                                    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="news-grid-box">
                                        <h1>19</h1>
                                        <p>Sep</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-grid-txt">
                                    <span>Finance</span>
                                    <h2>heading will be here</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Sept 19, 2020</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Admin</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium porro eligendi
                                        et
                                        excepturi minima tempora ex magni at fugit, voluptatibus animi minus. Non numquam
                                        vel
                                        impedit perferendis dolorum voluptatem quos.</p>
                                    <button><a href="#">Read More....</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-grid-image">
                                    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="news-grid-box">
                                        <h1>19</h1>
                                        <p>Sep</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-grid-txt">
                                    <span>Finance</span>
                                    <h2>heading will be here</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Sept 19, 2020</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Admin</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium porro eligendi
                                        et
                                        excepturi minima tempora ex magni at fugit, voluptatibus animi minus. Non numquam
                                        vel
                                        impedit perferendis dolorum voluptatem quos.</p>
                                    <button><a href="#">Read More....</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-grid-image">
                                    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="news-grid-box">
                                        <h1>19</h1>
                                        <p>Sep</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-grid-txt">
                                    <span>Finance</span>
                                    <h2>heading will be here</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Sept 19, 2020</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Admin</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium porro eligendi
                                        et
                                        excepturi minima tempora ex magni at fugit, voluptatibus animi minus. Non numquam
                                        vel
                                        impedit perferendis dolorum voluptatem quos.</p>
                                    <button><a href="#">Read More....</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-grid-image">
                                    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="news-grid-box">
                                        <h1>19</h1>
                                        <p>Sep</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-grid-txt">
                                    <span>Finance</span>
                                    <h2>heading will be here</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Sept 19, 2020</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Admin</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium porro eligendi
                                        et
                                        excepturi minima tempora ex magni at fugit, voluptatibus animi minus. Non numquam
                                        vel
                                        impedit perferendis dolorum voluptatem quos.</p>
                                    <button><a href="#">Read More....</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news-grid">
                                <div class="news-grid-image">
                                    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
                                    <div class="news-grid-box">
                                        <h1>19</h1>
                                        <p>Sep</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="news-grid-txt">
                                    <span>Finance</span>
                                    <h2>heading will be here</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Sept 19, 2020</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Admin</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium porro eligendi
                                        et
                                        excepturi minima tempora ex magni at fugit, voluptatibus animi minus. Non numquam
                                        vel
                                        impedit perferendis dolorum voluptatem quos.</p>
                                    <button><a href="#">Read More....</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
        
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-content">
                <h3>Code Opacity</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae at excepturi placeat omnis totam assumenda quae, </p>
                <ul class="socials">
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-bottom">
                <p> copyright &copy;2022 codeOpacity. designed by <span>Rahul Singh</span> </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#news-slider").owlCarousel({
                    items: 3, //10 items above 1000px browser width
                    itemsDesktop: [1000, 3], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
                    itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 2], // betweem 900px and 601px
                    itemsTablet: [600, 1], //2 items between 600 and 0;
                    itemsMobile: false,
                    autoPlay: true
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="home.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
    /*The css for that code */
    
    
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family:'Quicksand',sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    body{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background: url('bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .navigation ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .navigation ul li{
        padding: 10px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .navigation ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .navigation ul li a:hover{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }
    .mavigation ul li.active a{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }
    
    .header {
        padding: 15px 0px;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    .header-row{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    }
    
    
    .justify-content-between{
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .align-items{
        align-items: center;
    }
    .navigation{
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    .logo img{
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .nav-toggler{
        height: 34px;
        width: 44px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-toggler :focus{
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
    
    .nav-toggler span{
        height: 2px;
        width: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #000;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        transition:  all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .nav-toggler.active span{
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .nav-toggler span::before, .nav-toggler span::after{
        content :'';
        position : absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .nav-toggler span::after{
        transform: translateY(6px);
    }
    
    .nav-toggler.active span::after{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .nav-toggler span::before{
        transform: translateY(-6px);
    
    }
    
    .nav-toggler.active span::before{
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    
    
    /******* Slider *******/
    
    .display-flex{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .news-grid{
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .news-grid-image{
        width: 100%;
        height: 280px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .news-grid-image img{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .news-grid-box{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        background: #26ccca;
        left: -80px;
        top: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .news-grid-box h1{
        color:#fff;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .news-grid-box p{
        color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt span{
        color:#26ccca;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt h2{
        color: #111;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight:300;
        margin: 8px 10px 8px 0px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt ul li i{
        color: #26ccca;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt p{
        color: #222;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 170%;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        height: 75px;
        overflow: hidden;
    
    }
    
    .news-grid-txt button {
        background: #26ccca;
        padding: 8px 20px;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .news-grid-txt button a{
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration-line: none;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .news-grid:hover .news-grid-box{
        left: 15px;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .news-grid:hover .news-grid-image img{
        filter: grayscale(1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .news-grid:hover .news-grid-txt button a{
       letter-spacing: 2px ;
       transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    
    /*******Footer *******/
    
    footer{
        
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 20px;
        height: auto;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content h3{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        line-height: 3rem;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content .socials{
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content .socials li{
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content .socials li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content .socials li a i{
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        transition: color 0.4s ease;
    }
    
    footer .footer-content .socials li a:hover i{
        color: aqua;
    }
    
    footer .footer-bottom{
        background-color: #000;
        padding: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    footer .footer-bottom p{
        font-size: 14px;
        word-spacing: 2px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    footer .footer-bottom span{
        opacity: .4;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        .nav-toggler{
            display: block;
        }
        .navigation{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 12px;
            max-height: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            visibility: hidden;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .navigation.open{
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .navigation ul{
            width: 100%;
            border-top:  1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }
        .navigation ul li{
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
        }
        .navigation ul li a{ 
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .navigation ul li a:hover{
            color: #000;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    }

 /*Javascript file home.js */
const navToggler = document.querySelector(".nav-toggler");
navToggler.addEventListener("click", navToggle);

function navToggle(){
    navToggler.classList.toggle("active");
    const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");
    navigation.classList.toggle("open"); // here is the open toggler
    if(navigation.classList.contains("open")){
        navigation.style.maxHeight = navigation.scrollHeight + "px"; 
      
    }
    else{
        navigation.removeAttribute("style");

    } 

}
```

the code contains Javascript , Html file and Css file. In open class is added when the toggler gets on by using javascript and the open class is removed when toggler switches off.

in the @media screen when the width is changed to different size than desktop then I am hiding the navigation and displaying the nav-toggler and on clicking I am calling the javascript in which the .navigation.open visibility is made visible.

The functionality is working correctly. the problem is when I display the navigation with the help of javascript toggle functionality . the display of carousal is going down. I want that carousal to be stagnant in the position it is. the toggle should overlap and come at the top .

Comment: Take a look at this: [Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added the image at the top of the code section . please have a look what is happening. on clicking toggler the navigation is coming and the carousal is also moving which I don't want to happen. I want the carousal to be stagnant and get scrolled when I move the browser scroller. Not when the toggler gets active. https://i.stack.imgur.com/84qYC.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJ8P.jpg

Comment: can you please give me a solution for this and explain me . I don't want to fix the carousal. Carousal should be movable when I move scroll bar. It should not move when the toggle becomes active

Comment: @RahulSingh Just so I understand before I attempt this: do you want the menu to go *over* the carousel when opened and active and have the carousel not change position? Is that correct?

Comment: Absolute positioning can be problematic on mobile interfaces which often cut the display area by 1/3 to make room for a soft keyboard that dynamically appears and disappears based on user focus in textbox or input areas.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston What would you suggest that would improve my answer?