# Can you mix fixed/relative positioning?

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

Is it possible to have a relative DIV with a fixed position DIV inside that which is fixed relative to the container instead of being fixed to the window?

I tried the solutions shown in this answer:

[Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

But none seem to work. Here's the HTML/CSS that I'm using (it's the pink DIV in the corner that I want to be fixed relative to its container):

```html
<html>

<body>

  hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu
  hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu
  hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu
  hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu
  hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu
  hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho


  <div style="transform: translateZ(0); width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: #ddd; overflow: auto; padding: 10px; position: relative">
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 20px; background-color: pink; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid gray">Blah!</div>
    gygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghj
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to have a relative DIV with a fixed position DIV inside that which is fixed relative to the container instead of being fixed to the window?"_ - Yes, that would be an `absolute` descendant of a `fixed` (or `sticky`) ancestor - and descendants of the that `absolute` element could _then_ also have ``position: relative;` on themselves if you really wanted.

Comment: Here's some HTML that I ended up going with: https://codepen.io/rgraph/pen/OJrEogY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`position: fixed` will always relate to the browser window, regardless where it's located in the code and regardless if it has a positioned element as parent.

What you want to use here is `position: absolute`. This will  relate to the first parent that is positioned (relative, absolute, fixed, sticky).

```html
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho


<div style="transform: translateZ(0); width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: #ddd; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px; background-color: pink; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid gray; width: 100px;">Blah!</div>

    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
gygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghj
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting the position to absolute will mean that when the gray DIV is scrolled left or right the pink blah! will scroll left or right too. I want the pink Blah! to stay fixed to the right-hand-side.

Comment: @Richard i edited my answer and added a code snippet. You'll need an additional div surrounding the text inside the grey box. The pink pox is positioned absolute to the grey box, while the additional box inside the grey one has the overflow: auto.

Comment: Note that  fixed does not always relate to the viewport. "An exception to this occurs if one of the element's ancestors is a fixed containing block because its transform property has a value other than none." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#fixed_positioning

Comment: Great - thank you very much!

Comment: Here's some HTML that I ended up going with: https://codepen.io/rgraph/pen/OJrEogY

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to the previous answer plus OP's comment to it:

You can use `position: absolute` and add `left: calc(95vw - 100px);` instead of the `right` setting, which positions it at 5% distance from the right side of the window – 95% of the window width minus the defined width of the element itself. (Adjust values as needed)

Added note after comments: This CSS-only solution is intended for the situation when the existing HTML structure *cannot be changed* (the OP didn't go into detail about this, so I wouldn't know if that's the case). If the HTML *can* be edited, it would be better to change the HTML structure and apply according css settings to those elements.

```html
<html>
<body>

hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho
hu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo hohu hu ohjo ho


<div style="transform: translateZ(0); width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: #ddd; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: calc(95vw - 100px); background-color: pink; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid gray; width: 100px; box-sizing: border-box;">Blah!</div>

    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
gygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghjgygygffgvfvghj
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional remark, moved from comment to answer: If you don't want a "relative" (5%/vw) distance from the right edge of the window, but a fixed *pixel* distance, you can also use `left: calc(100vw - 150px);`in the above example, where the `px` value is the sum of the element's `width` and the desired fixed distance from the right (to be adjusted as needed)

Please also note that I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to your divs to *include* (instead of the default *adding*) the padding in their defined widths.

Comment: why would you say left with vague calculation instead of right with an absolute value?

Comment: @jessman5 1.) That's no "vague calculation" but responsive – always 5% away from the right edge of the window. 2.) Because `right` will relate to the container's edge, not to the window width as the OP demanded in their responese/comment to the other answer.

Comment: "instead of being fixed to the window" was the request though. If you want sth 5% away from the right of the window (fixed positioned), 'right: 5%`is better, because it's much more descriptive of what it actually does and it's simple. It's also responsive. And in case you don't know: 95vw is not always 95vw, it depends if the scrollbar is visible or not. So there's quite an uncertainty with your suggestion.

Comment: @jessman5 What are you complaining about? Your answer is marked as accepted. I just provided an alternative solution. Just relax...

Comment: Not complaining. Just leaving noticeable insights related to your suggestion.

Comment: @jessman5 To me this looks like nagging rather than "noticable insights". Imaginge for example if the HTML structure is given and can't be changed, which the OP didn't write about, but could be – in this case a pure CSS sollution (like mine) would be needed. A "noticable insight" as well ;-)

Comment: who is complaining now? I will no longer participate in this.

Comment: Here's some HTML that I ended up going with: https://codepen.io/rgraph/pen/OJrEogY