# making an image stick relative to other elements while page zooms in or out

Tags: css, position, fixed

i have an image, essentially a white rectangle, that I'm
trying to use as a screen between a top layer logo
and the text below.

the logo is part of the header and acts as 'sticky' -
not moving when y-scrolling the page.

what I'm failing at is making my rectangle stay fixed
relative to it's parent (the header) when zooming takes place.

Instead, the rectangle floats away with each zoom.

Header is position fixed, the img is absolute.

p.s. tried searching for an answer. the above setting
taken from: [Can I position an element fixed relative to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209814/can-i-position-an-element-fixed-relative-to-parent)

please kindly help,
yaron h.

Comment: Can you provide some code (css and html)?

Comment: Maybe try positioning the logo with float? it's hard to help with no code or better yet a link/fiddle..

Comment: I managed to solve the issue after nesting my img one DIV down... don'r really understand why it works, but it does :->