# is there any trick for freeze an html element relative to a container is either by css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing research on this topic by the last day but i have not found any solution. i'm badly stuck in my project. Please someone help me to out.

My related search is [Can I position an element fixed relative to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209814/can-i-position-an-element-fixed-relative-to-parent).

But this is not able to fulfill my will.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: `position:fixed` is for this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post what you have tried and where you are getting problem so that we can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/L8ov9bot/) for this.

What you want specifically is `position:relative;` on the parent and `position:absolute;` on the child element you want to position.

(Then set the position of the child element)

**EDIT**

New [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/L8ov9bot/3/) using jQuery UI .position()

HTML

```
<div class="anchor">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <button class="fixed-button">Fixed position button</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $(".fixed-button").each(function(arg, el){
        $(el).position({
            of:  $(el).closest(".anchor")[0],
            my:  "left top",
            at:  "left+500 top+10"
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

I just realized that this can be done by CSS only now that we have the "anchor" surrounding the content and the button. See this new and (hopefully) final [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/L8ov9bot/5/)

CSS

```
.anchor{
    position: relative;
}

.fixed-button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: how can i freeze element with abosolute position @Argon

Comment: Did you look at the "?" in the JSFiddle?

Comment: yes i have seen but i want to freze button inside scrollable container

Comment: I have updated my answer with one way to accomplish this with jQuery UI.

Comment: +1 I have added some <br> to your example to have result more visible [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mntuqpge/)