# css pseudo element (triangle outside the tr) position misaligned when scrollbar appears

Tags: css, angularjs, scrollbar

I have a panel which height is fixed and `overflow-y:auto;`  in this panel I am displaying table and when user click on one of the row, triangle on right side of row appears that is working fine till scrollbar doesn't comes on the table list.  if there is scrollbar than right arraow appears down the panel.  how to fix this issue?

Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/cedewiharu/edit?html,css,output) and also I have added the complete code snippet below and the image with the issue [image: relevant image]

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('TableController', function($log, $scope) {
      $scope.tables = [{
          "name": "one_table",
          "purpose": "test"
        },
        {
          "name": "one_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "two_",
          "purpose": "test"

        }, {
          "name": "three_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "four_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "five_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "six_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "seven_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "eight_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "nine_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "ten_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }
      ];
      $scope.tindex = -1;
      $scope.rowClicked = function(idx) {
        $scope.tindex = idx;
      }
    });
})();
```

```css
.panel-body {
  display: block;
  height: 230px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.arrow-left:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #eee;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  float: right;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="TableController">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-define="tables">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <span>Tables</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" ng-click="rowClicked($index)" ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'arrow-left' : ''">
                <td>{{table.name}}</td>
                <td>{{table.purpose}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please help me to find the right approach.

on the other hand can we accomplish this with angular-custom directive ?

Comment: You are required to supply the markup that shows the problem here, not a third-party site which can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: To the close requester; will you explain Why this question if off topic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve In addition, your CSS is not the complete markup that shows the problem. A link to a jsfiddle is not acceptable except to supplement the code you supply.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for the information; I have added the code snippet here within question.

Comment: and these third party sites is being used in every 3rd questions, internal code snippet should be minimal but the external link is for the viewers so that they can try with that fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved this by custom directive and little bit CSS and with help of my colleague.

add a custom directive in *panel-body* and calculate the position of clicked row and the panel height and reposition the arrow class ( without any pseudo element). Below is full code

```js
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app',[])
        .controller('TableController', function($log, $scope) {
        $scope.tables = [
        {
          "name": "one_table",
          "columns": [
            {"name": "id"},{"name": "f_name"}           
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "one_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "two_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "three_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "four_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "five_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "six_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "seven_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "eight_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "nine_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "ten_",
          "columns": []
        }
      ];
      $scope.tindex = -1;
      $scope.rowClicked = function (idx) {
        $scope.tblRowClicked = idx;
        $scope.tindex = idx;
      }
    }).directive('showArrow', function($window, $timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    // change the arrow position
                    var minHeight, maxHeight, maxWidth, tableHeight, style;
                    var row, rowPos, arrow;
                    var changeArrowPosition = function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            row = element.find('.hover');
                            rowPos = row.position(); // get position of clicked row
                            //console.log("rowPos:minHeight:maxHeight:tableHeight", rowPos, minHeight, maxHeight,tableHeight);
                            arrow = element.children('.dir-right');
                            arrow.hide();
                            if (rowPos) {
                                if (rowPos.top >= minHeight && rowPos.top <= maxHeight) {
                                    style = {"top": rowPos.top + "px"};
                                    arrow.css(style);
                                    // if table height is lesser than panel height
                                    if (tableHeight <= maxHeight && maxWidth > 435) {
                                        style = {"margin": "auto 5px"};
                                        arrow.css(style);
                                    }
                                    arrow.addClass('arrow-right').show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    element.on("click scroll", function() {
                        var elem = angular.element(this);
                        maxHeight = elem.height(); // panel height
                        maxWidth = elem.width(); //panel width
                        tableHeight = elem.children('table').height(); // table height
                        minHeight = elem.children('table').find('tr').eq(0).height(); // firt row height
                        changeArrowPosition();
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    
})();
```

```css
.panel-body {
    display: block;
    height: 230px;
    padding: 0px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr.hover {
  background-color: #e5ee4f!important;
}
.arrow-right {
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #e5ee4f;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: right;
    height: 0px;
    left: 96%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
}

.dir-right {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="TableController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-define="tables">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Tables</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" show-arrow>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                  <tbody >
                      <tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" ng-click="rowClicked($index)" ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'hover' : ''">
                          <td>{{table.name}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <i ng-if="vm.tblRowClicked === vm.tindex" class="dir-right"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [Working Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/fagocas/edit?html,css,js,output)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the pseudoelement isn't being positioned correctly, even when the `tr` is given a `position: relative`

This issue can be fixed by adding the pseudoelement to the td instead.

```
<tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" >
   <td ng-click="rowClicked($index)" ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'arrow-left' : ''">{{table.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

and altering the CSS slightly:

```
table tbody tr td {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-left:after {
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #eee;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: right;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

I'm not sure if moving the click event to the `td` is a solution for you however.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kikuninaru/edit?html,css,output)

**update**

To work with multiple `td`, update CSS as below:

```
table tbody tr td {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-left td:last-of-type:after {
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #eee;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: right;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: 0;
    width: 0px;
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tovibaromu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I have 3 *td* in each *tr* in my original table data  and that way doesn't help me .

Comment: i have added this class on last td of row but now new issue comes up. the triangle coming inside the panel body but i want it outside of it

Comment: @pro.mean If the table you're using is different than the example you've provided in the question can you create a new demo? It's difficult to help otherwise

Comment: Thanks for the response but I want that triangle outside of container but in your fiddle it's within the container (panel) .

Comment: also if I trying to add `right:-30px` attribute in the CSS then triangle goes behind the scrollbar..that's the issue... if it will be outside of the controller then there will be no such problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply `position: relative` to the table element, the arrow won't escape the container. For some reason the spec says a `position: relative` on `table-row` and other table elements are `undefined`.

Here's the spec for more info:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect like this.

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('TableController', function($log, $scope) {
      $scope.tables = [{
          "name": "one_table",
          "purpose": "test"
        },
        {
          "name": "one_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "two_",
          "purpose": "test"

        }, {
          "name": "three_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "four_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "five_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "six_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "seven_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "eight_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "nine_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }, {
          "name": "ten_",
          "purpose": "test"
        }
      ];
      $scope.tindex = -1;
      $scope.rowClicked = function(idx) {
        $scope.tindex = idx;
      }
    });
})();
```

```css
.panel-body {
 display: block;
    height: 230px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

table {

    color:#000!important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.arrow-left:after {
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #eee;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: right;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 8px;
    width: 0px;
}
.arrow-left1:after {
        border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid #eee;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="TableController">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-define="tables">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <span>Tables</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" ng-click="rowClicked($index)">
                <td>{{table.name}}</td>
                <td>{{table.purpose}}</td>
                <td ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'arrow-left' : ''"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
         <div class="panel-body no-padding">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" ng-click="rowClicked($index)" ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'arrow-left1' : ''">
                <td>{{table.name}}</td>
                <td>{{table.purpose}}</td>  
                <td>{{table.purpose}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want that triangle outside of the container (Tables Panel) scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

please check these result, i think its working the correct way of you expecting

```js
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app',[])
        .controller('TableController', function($log, $scope) {
        $scope.tables = [
        {
          "name": "one_table",
          "columns": [
            {"name": "id"},{"name": "f_name"}           
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "one_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "two_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "three_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "four_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "five_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "six_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "seven_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "eight_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "nine_",
          "columns": []
        }, {
          "name": "ten_",
          "columns": []
        }
      ];
      $scope.tindex = -1;
      $scope.rowClicked = function (idx) {
        $scope.tindex = idx;
      }
    });
})();
```

```css
.panel-body {
    display: block;
    height: 230px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.table tbody tr td {
    border-top: 0px !important;
}
.arrow-left:after {
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #ccc;
    /* border-right: 20px solid transparent; */
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    float: right;
    height: 0px;
    /* margin: 1px auto; */
    position: relative;
    right:8px;
    width: 0px;
}
table tr {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  
}
table tr td {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="TableController">
<div class="row col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-4" data-define="tables">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Tables</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body no-padding">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                  <tbody >
                      <tr ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index" ng-click="rowClicked($index)" ng-class="tindex === $index ? 'arrow-left' : ''">
                          <td>{{table.name}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" data-define="tables">HERE </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind efforts but my requirement is to display that triangle outside the container.