# Make arrow in css in middle of boxes

Tags: html, css

I have below css class which is applied with my divs.

```
.rightarrow{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #aaaaa9;
    }
```

Below is my markup:

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="tabs">
   <!-- tabs start  -->
   <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- part 1 Will execute 2 times as  per filters-->
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="volkswagen">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 1</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 2</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 3</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 4</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- End part 2 -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- ./Tabs -->
```

I am getting below result.
[image]

Also the current applied styles are :

[image]

I want these arrows in the middle, between of these rectangular boxes. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

@Irina : This is what now the output is after adding styles provided by you.:

[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @zdhim, Could you please create full code snippet to demonstrate the result as on your picture? If I try your existing code, I don't have similar result.

Comment: Do you mean, aligned vertically, inside the rectangles or what specifically?

Comment: had similar issues, you can check the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046672/css-pseudo-element-triangle-outside-the-tr-position-misaligned-when-scrollbar) that may help u

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to manipulate with your arrow element, if you create it like a pseudo element. Please check an example:

```css
.col-xs-5ths:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -28px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #aaaaa9;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100px; /* just for demo */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-5ths">test test test</div>    
<div class="col-xs-5ths">test</div>
<div class="col-xs-5ths">test test</div>
```

**EDIT:** Please try new version below:

```css
.col-xs-5ths:nth-of-type(1):after,
.col-xs-5ths:nth-of-type(2):after,
.col-xs-5ths:nth-of-type(3):after,
.col-xs-5ths:nth-of-type(4):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -31px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #aaaaa9;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.col-xs-5ths {
  width: calc(20% - 40px);
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100px; /* just for demo */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- I've included bootstrap 3 css, not sure what version you have -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="tabs">
   <!-- tabs start  -->
   <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- part 1 Will execute 2 times as  per filters-->
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="volkswagen">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 1</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 2</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 3</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 4</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 5</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 6</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 4</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5ths ">
               <div class="light-text-box">
                  <h4>Test 7</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dark-box-outer">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- End part 2 -->
</div>
<!-- ./Tabs -->
```

Comment: Hi @Irina, I have updated the markup, might be its clear for you now, arrow was need only for first row. Now its coming in between all columns. PFA

Comment: Also, border is overlaying with each other.

Comment: @zdhim, thank you for updates. I’ll check it in several hours.

Comment: @zdhim, please check new code snippet below `EDIT` section.