# Bootstrap keep navbar items in line with the site content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I try to have the brand and the dropdown (on the right) in line with the content of the page. The general design is to have one content column which takes col-8 on larger devices and col-12 on smaller devices. I want to have the navbar and the footer always 100% width (I mean the color of the navbar) but the content in that navbar should be the same width as the content of the page. I tried different options but never been able to do it right.

Here's the result of my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5HvA.png)
I want the "Brand" be always in line with "Some text". Similar with "X" but on the right.

I tried moving the row/col/container elements around but it looks like the "nav" element CSS is defined in the way that prevents my design. I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and I suppose I might get some ideas wrong here.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="container mx-auto pt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
              <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      X
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card border-light mb-3">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Some text</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <footer class="bg-light text-center fixed-bottom">
              <div class="text-center text-secondary p-3">
                Footer
              </div>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. Using `fixed-top` makes the navbar position: fixed and therefore it [no longer flows with or is relative to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209814/can-i-position-an-element-fixed-relative-to-parent) other page content. If you want it's width relative to parent column it's contained in, remove `fixed-top`. Also the outer row/col are not necessary.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> X </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <!-- BODY WRAPPER -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- content -->
                <div class="card border-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">Some text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="bg-light text-center fixed-bottom">
                    <div class="text-center text-secondary p-3"> Footer </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/9RKAXMhD2U

Comment: Yeah but then the navbar is not colored on the sides. Do I need to create separate side containers to keep the grey color over 100% width?