# Div positioned fixed disapears on anchor click

Tags: css, css-position

I have a banner with some Social media icons on the left:

```
.social_share-wrapper {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

[image]

But when I click on an anchor in the page, like:

```
<a href="#main-up"><img src="path/to/image/image.png" /><h3>Click</h3></a>
```

And scroll back to the top of my page, I get this:

[image]

Does it make any sense? Or did someone already had this before?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that does this?

Comment: cant really tell from what you showed us here

Comment: Apparently fixed elements do not have default top and left values of zero. You should set them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712047/positionfixed-when-left-top-right-bottom-arent-specified-desired-results-in