# Fixed position on top

Tags: css, css-position

I try to create a div semi transparent on top of the content of a page. This div should be 100% the width and hight of the window.

If I put the transparent div after the content it does not appear. I do not understand why? This div is positioned fixed and by definition fixed position "The element is positioned relative to the browser window"

This can be solved just putting .trans first in the html, but this is a simplified case of a much complex page. On the other hand, I would like to understand the problem.

So why a fixed div should be first to be seen?

Here is to play: http://jsfiddle.net/26dPg/

CSS:

```
body { margin:0; }

.trans{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    margin:0;
    opacity:0.7; filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:5;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    margin:30px auto;
    width:95%; max-width:890px; height:1200px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div class="trans"></div> /*if this div goes after #content, this cannot be seen*/
```

Comment: You are likely seeing something like this as you have not specified a `top` property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712047/positionfixed-when-left-top-right-bottom-arent-specified-desired-results-in

Comment: Yup, setting `top: 0;` will fix this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/26dPg/1/)

Comment: Yes, top:0 solves the problem. Thank you. But I do not understand why? Can you explain it please? If fixed is respect the window and I put 100%, why top is needed?

Answer (score 1):

In you .trans class, just add :

```
top:0;
```

Comment: Yes, top:0 solves the problem. Thank you. But I do not understand why? Can you explain it please? without that top:0; where is .trans?

Comment: It seems that you have to give a property for the position fixed (top, bottom, left or right).

Comment: Now I see, but I do not understand why. If I say the fixed div should be 100% and by definition fixed position is relative to the window, why is it necessary to say anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `#content` position to `absolute`.

```
  body { margin:0; }

    .trans{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%; height:100%;
        margin:0;
        opacity:0.7; filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
        background-color:red;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index:5;
    }

    #content {
        position:absolute;
        margin:30px auto;
        width:95%; max-width:890px; height:1200px;
        z-index:1;
        background-color:blue;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Comment: absolute will only work if the page is smaller than the viewport, and the user does not scroll.

Comment: This is not the solution... and yes adding `top: 0;` will fix this. As you have now seen due to the first comment linking to a similar question and the second comment that shows an working example.