# How to add content to page right after a fixed navigation bar which has variable height?

Tags: html, css

Currently, if I create a div just after my navigation bar it hides underneath the navigation bar. I'm new to CSS but I'm quite sure this has to do with the fixed navigation bar being taken out of the document flow.

Here is the current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/8pwcobuz/

**HTML structure:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


<body>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">List item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown">List item 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">List item 3.1111111111111</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 3.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">List item 5.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 5.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">List item 5.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>  

    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
#nav    {
    background-color: #333;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px;
}

#content    {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

I've tried two approaches.

First of all, I placed the navigation bar outside of the body element and adding a top-margin to the body (if this is terrible please let me know), but it didn't seem to work. My reasoning here was that fixed elements are fixed relative to the viewport, while all other positioned elements are positioned relative to the body. So by giving a margin-top to the body and just adding content like I normally would, it would work right? But it didn't.

Secondly, I tried to create a div that contains the content of the entire page, also with a top-margin to adjust for the space taken up by the fixed navigation element. This didn't work either.

In both cases, the navigation bar moves down as well when I set the margin-top property, and I only want the content to move. What am I missing here?

Additional question: Is there any way right now to do this in a responsive way without using Javascript or jQuery? I'm trying to avoid those for now, since I'm just starting out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem here is that a fixed element is out of the document flow - e.g. it cannot push your content down, while paddings and margins for your content are irrelevant to your header. One solution would be to set the header's position to fixed after a scroll dynamically.

Comment: I found the problem! Turns out I never set the top position of the header to 0. By doing that it all works great now :) I still do not know why that was necessary though, since the fixed header was added first in the html, so why does its position change when I add a margin-top to the content div?

Comment: This is the exact reason I referred to the header being out of the document flow. When you want an element `fixed` you need to Fix it somewhere. :)

Comment: But if it's taken out of the document flow, why does it move when I add a margin-top to a static element?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. If you add margin to it, it will move, because it is being removed from the document flow, away from its relatives, not away from its own meaning. Have a read - https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: I've read the article:) Problem is that I never added a margin to the fixed navigation-bar element (ul) and when I add a margin to the static content element (div), which comes after the navigation bar as seen in the html structure, somehow the position of the navigation bar changes as well.

Comment: The problem that you are describing is not happening in the Fiddle you provided. I've added margins to the main content, everything is okay.

Comment: I assume that it only worked after you set the top position property to 0? My question was more or less what was happening to the fixed element when its top position was not set to 0. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: All the positioning is being calculated relatively and it adjusts itself, it does not zero-out the positions by default. Here is what you are looking for -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712047/positionfixed-when-left-top-right-bottom-arent-specified-desired-results-in