# CSS Fixed header- Does it need two positions?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I seen some examples of this floating around, but I am wondering if it is *necessary* to declare two postions when fixing a header?

For example, do you need to declare `top:0;` **and** `left:0;`?:

```
.header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

Or can you get away with just `top:0;`?:

```
.header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width:100%;
}
```

I just a little perplexed since I've seen examples with both, but I can't find a reasonable explanation if setting `top:0; left:0'` is necessary/better than just `top:0;` for a fixed header?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712047/positionfixed-when-left-top-right-bottom-arent-specified-desired-results-in

Answer (score 0):

Since your `width` is `100%` it won't matter either way. However, if the width wasn't `100%` and if `<nav>` was a child of an element that's not positioned in the top left, your nav would be positioned horizontally according to the parent element. (Not all the way to the left)

Answer (score 0):

If the `top` or `left` is not declared, the default is `left:auto` or `top:auto`. auto means for `left` (for fixed positioned elements):

- if right and width is defined, the left is calculated
- if width or right is undefined the left is calculated from default flow of the content in non-scrolled position like for block elements.

Then if you use `position:fixed` there often will be needed to use left/right and top/bottom styles.

To view differences use `margin-right:-100px` and put your header in other element for example second cell of table.

Test here - you can add `left:0` and retest. 
https://jsfiddle.net/vau6g09f/