# I've been trying to make my NAVBAR fixed to the top when scrolling. But it remains fixed in the middle

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've been trying to make my NAVBAR fixed to the top when scrolling. But it remains fixed in the initial position without moving to the stop and being fixed as I want. Code below,

I've tried W3 School tutorials, bootstrap and materialize. But nothing seemed to help. This is my last resort.

```css
div.wrapper {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #80F;
  border-radius: 0%;
  position: fixed;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #6900c4;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #490089;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- The NAV BAR IS BELOW THE LOGO -->

<!--LOGO-->
<center>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.englishessays.online"><img src="img/logoheader.png" alt="Logo" width="65%"></a>
</center>
<br>
<hr class="line" color="black">
<br>

<!--NAV-->

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="https://www.englishessays.online">Home</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.englishessays.online/essays.php" class="active">Essays</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/dialogues.php">Dialogues</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/speeches.php">Speeches</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/stories.php">Stories</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/poems.php">Poems</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/about.php">About</a>
  <a target="_blank" href="www.englishessays.online/contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

The output should be: NAVBAR fixed to the top when scrolling.
Error is: NAVBAR is fixed in the initial position without moving to the top.

Answer (score 2):

You may need:

```
.topnav 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #80F;
    border-radius:0%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Its always a good idea to specify anchor points (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`) when using `fixed` or `absolute` positioning.

Comment: It's not the exact solution I expected. But still thanks! I adjusted the logo to be below the nav bar, then the nav bar position won't be a problem.

Comment: @Wije I would still recommend specifying your desired position explicitly. If you're not going to however, make sure you check it in all browsers you're targeting. Fixed position without explicit positioning can [behave weirdly in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712047/positionfixed-when-left-top-right-bottom-arent-specified-desired-results-in)

Comment: Thank You, I mentioned TOP as you said and moved the logo below the nav bar. It works fine now.